# Custom NavigationBar height with button and label

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a `UINavigationBar` that looks like this:

[image: need]

This is what I've managed to achieve...

[image: attempt]

My first idea was to try creating a back button on the `UINavigationBar` and just removing the line between the first header of the `UITableView`. Problem with that is, the `UITableView` header is *not* sticky. Can someone help me out with this?

I'm using Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that with the `prefersLargeTitles` setting on `UINavigationBar` available from iOS 11. If you're using a Storyboard, select the navigation bar, and check the "Prefers Large Titles" box.

[image: Screenshot of navigation bar setting to prefer large titles]

In code, you can set the navigation bar's `prefersLargeTitles` property to `true`.

When you show a detail view controller, you may want to have more control over whether it uses the large title or not. You can do this on the view controller.

Easiest way to do that is in code. Something like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Disable large titles for this view controller
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never // Options are automatic, always, or never.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this: Create a new `UIViewController` and put a View at the top of it as my header then use a `UITableView` as opposed to a `UITableViewController`.